# Django. Download Image with requests - edit with PIL - save to model

Tags: django, python-imaging-library, stringio

I'm having trouble with this process: I want to download an image using `requests`, then crop it with `PIL` and then save it to the a model `ImageField`.

This is what I have now:

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
import requests
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image


def get_img_url(url_img):
    answer = requests.get(url_img)
    image = Image.open(StringIO(answer.content))
    new_image = image.crop((22, 44, 221, 165))

    return image


class FormNewCard(forms.ModelForm):

....

    def save(self, **kwargs):

        url_image = self.cleaned_data['imagen']
        pil_img = get_img_url(url_img)
        stringio_obj = StringIO()
        try:
            pil_img.save(stringio_obj, format="JPG")
            final_image = stringio_obj.getvalue()
            self.image = ContentFile(final_image)
        finally:
            stringio_obj.close()
```

I get this error:

```
       pil_img.save(stringio_obj, format="JPG")

       KeyError at /hisoka/new_card/
       'JPG'
```

I know the error is purely a PIL problem, I'm not sure how to solve it (tried several times), but also, I'd like to know if what I'm doing is correct or if there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: You mean upload I suppose...

Comment: Try setting `format="JPEG"` instead of `"JPG"`

Comment: @JRodDynamite It worked when I did that ... thnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, you get a `KeyError` with the key being `'JPG'`, it's fairly certain that Pillow doesn't recognize it.

But if you have a look at the [docs](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html#jpeg), you'll notice that it is spelled `JPEG`. Hence, simply set `format='JPEG'`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a [snippet](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/10460/) I found:

```
from PIL import Image as Img
import StringIO

def resize():
    img = Img.open(StringIO.StringIO(self.image.read()))
    if img.mode != 'RGB':
        img = img.convert('RGB')
        img.thumbnail((800, self.image.height * 800 / self.image.width), Img.ANTIALIAS) # 800 is just a number I pick, enter whatever you want here
        output = StringIO.StringIO()
        img.save(output, format='JPEG', quality=70)
        output.seek(0)
        self.image = InMemoryUploadedFile(output, 'ImageField', "%s.jpg" %      self.image.name.split('.')[0], 'image/jpeg', output.len, None)
```

I tested the snippet above and it definitely works.

If you look at the original snippet, the author overrides the `save` method of the model which stores the `ImageField`. It might be applicable to your case too.